# Calling blocking functions on UI thread from background thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm building an application that needs to be able to maintain a connection to a server by replying to keep alive packets sent every 8 seconds.
This thread should also handle information when sent from the server when it comes in.
To this end I need to know if its possible to have the background thread trigger an event to cause the GUI thread to dsiplay a dialog box with the handled information.

I'm having trouble as my current attempt blocks the background thread and thus the keep alive responses fail.

```
    //So far I create these globals
    delegate void EventHandler();
    event EventHandler _show;

    //In the form constructor i add the event handler
    _show += new EventHandler(showSecond);

    // in the Child thread I invoke the event
    _show.Invoke();

   // And the event handler function
   public void showSecond()
    {
            form2.ShowDialog();
            updateCheckList(form2.selected);
            form2.selected = new List<element>();
    }
```

Please let me know if you need any more detail

Comment: Is this a WPF application or winforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure your GUI operations are done on the GUI thread. You normally do that using `Invoke` - there are plenty of examples around, but basically it is something like:

```
   private delegate void MyDelegate(int param);
   private void MyFunc(int aParam)
   {     
      // Invoke is required if we aren't on the GUI thread
      if (this.InvokeRequired)
      {
         // MyFunc will be called asynchronously on the
         // GUI thread.
         //
         this.BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(MyFunc), 
                                          new object[] {aParam});
         return;
      }
      // We only get here if we're running on the GUI thread
      // So we can put GUI ops here safely.
    }
```

Comment: Thank you mate I'd used this method for edittingcontrol parameters but I wasn't familiar with how to use it to call functions.